# Arranging data in tabular format from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list as below and looking to display it in 5 columns one under the other

```
lsit = ['Alexander City', 'Andalusia', 'Anniston', 'Athens', 'Atmore', 
        'Auburn', 'Bessemer', 'Birmingham', 'Chickasaw', 'Clanton', 
        'Cullman', 'Decatur', 'Demopolis', 'Dothan', 'Enterprise', 
        'Eufaula', 'Florence', 'Fort Payne', 'Gadsden', 'Greenville',
        'Guntersville', 'Huntsville']
```

Tried with `print("\t".join(lsit))` but the data is not populated properly

```
>>> print("\t".join(lsit))
Alexander City  Andalusia   Anniston    Athens  Atmore  Auburn  Bessemer    Birmingham  Chickasaw   Clanton Cullman DecaturDemopolis    Dothan  Enterprise  Eufaula Florence    Fort Payne  Gadsden Greenville  Guntersville    Huntsville
```

Can someone guide how can this be achieved in python?

Answer (score 1):

Well all you're missing is to print them in groups of five:

```py
for i in range(0, len(lsit), 5):
    print("\t".join(lsit[i: i+5]))
```

Which gives:

```
Alexander City  Andalusia   Anniston    Athens  Atmore
Auburn  Bessemer    Birmingham  Chickasaw   Clanton
Cullman Decatur Demopolis   Dothan  Enterprise
Eufaula Florence    Fort Payne  Gadsden Greenville
Guntersville    Huntsville
```

Comment: thts works Thanks. is it possible to be adjusted as per the screen size as if this is viewed in larger screen would still give me 5 columns

Answer (score 0):

**You can used this solution:**

```
lsit = [['Alexander City', 'Andalusia', 'Anniston', 'Athens', 'Atmore'], 
        ['Auburn', 'Bessemer', 'Birmingham', 'Chickasaw', 'Clanton'],
        ['Cullman', 'Decatur', 'Demopolis', 'Dothan', 'Enterprise'], 
        ['Eufaula', 'Florence', 'Fort Payne', 'Gadsden', 'Greenville'],
        ['Guntersville', 'Huntsville']]
for i in range(len(lsit)):
    for j in range(len(lsit[i])):
        print("\t",lsit[i][j], end=' ')
    print()
```